# Is it possible to set a breakpoint at PHP spl_autoload_register?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, breakpoints

I'd like to know who calls [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) in my application. Specifically, I'm using CakePHP, so a simple combination of `find` and `grep` in the source files should suffice, but I'm wondering if there is a way to set a *breakpoint* in Eclipse via XDebug, so the PHP interpreter will stop when the Cake scripts invoke that function and will show me the file and line number where this happens.

You know, I'm not able to manually set the breakpoint because the function is not defined in any PHP file, so effectively I'm asking if there is a way to trace calls to functions defined in PHP extensions (possibly in native code), even if I obviously won't have any way to step into machine code.

Comment: Did you not try searching the Cake source for spl_autoload_register in the text and set breakpoints at all of those points where it occurs?

Comment: The problem is not *finding*, is **how to reach there**. I was looking for a debugger solution just for curiosity, because there are lots (and fancy) ways a function can be invoked without passing via the usual `function_name()` in the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do something sneaky with a creative use of [`override_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) and/or [`rename_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php), although it's likely to be a lot easier to do something with a `grep -r` of the source code (or, even better, [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/))